# parse push notification error when using geo-query

Tags: curl, parse-platform, push-notification

Please help!!! 
I am trying to send push notification through Parse based on geo-query. I think i am following the document exactly, but get 102 error saying query is invalid.

I have an _Installation class, and _User class. The _Installation class has a column named "user" pointing to the _User class (just like the parse document instructed). 
_Installation class data:
[image]
_User class data:
[image]

I used curl command exactly like the parse document described:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id:#############" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: #############" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "where": {
          "user": {
            "$inQuery": {
              "location": {
                "$nearSphere": {
                  "__type": "GeoPoint",
                  "latitude": 37.0,
                  "longitude": -122.0
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "data": {
          "alert": "testing!"
        }
      }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/push
```

But in the response, I get: {"code":102,"error":"bad type for %!s(MISSING)"}

What's wrong? Please help, i think at least a handful of people are having the same issue. thanks.